# Find the URL (drop location) of files dragged from an App to the Finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

When acting as a dragging source, it is possible for an App to drag file paths.
That enables you to drag files from your app to another location on Disk using the Finder.

I'm using a tableview, each row represents a file.

When `- (void)tableView:draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` is called, 
**How can we get the new URLs that the dropped files now point at ?**

The issue with this is that even if the drag operation has ended, it  doesn't necessarily mean that the files have successfully been moved. The whole file-move operation seems opaque and performed silently by the OS.